# Xlint:invalidAbsoluteTypeName

Tags: spring, pointcut

I see the below Spring framework exception while server start-up

**

```
> Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is
> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: warning no match for this type
> name: com.java.site.admi.controllers.HomeController
> [Xlint:invalidAbsoluteTypeName]
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:527)
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
```

**

anyone encounter this before ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It means that your pointcut wants to match class `com.java.site.admi.controllers.HomeController`, but cannot find it. Maybe something is wrong with the class or package name, e.g. maybe you wanted to write `admin`instead of `admi`.

Comment: You are right .The dependency with the jar file which contain the class 'HomeController' was not included in the WAR . Spring loaders was looking that class on Runtime . Thanks .