# Java Spring AOP: Can I ignore Xlint:invalidAbsoluteTypeName error which caused by pointcuts to classes which I don't use?

Tags: java, classpath, spring-aop

I have an issue concerning a generic component and one (of a dozen) application(s). My component has point cuts to many annotations, which could be used within classes and methods in my apps. When all annotations are present on the classpath, everything works fine. But not in all my apps I have these dependencies. The quick fix is, of course, add them, but that gives my app a lot of code which I don't need in that app. I'm searching for a way to ignore the `Xlint:invalidAbsoluteTypeName` error as stated here: **[Xlint:invalidAbsoluteTypeName](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23780951/xlintinvalidabsolutetypename)**

So what I have:

- I have many apps with Soap/JMS connections, and all are annotated with the @Annotation `org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.annotation.Endpoint`.
- I have my pointcut in my generic component (jar): 
  `@Around("within(@org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.annotation.Endpoint *)")`

And the result is:

- All apps having the Spring WS dependency along with my generic component have no issues
- Apps which don't have the annotation, cannot start due to `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: warning no match for this type name: org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.annotation.Endpoint [Xlint:invalidAbsoluteTypeName]` (which is obvious, see the link)

So the problem looks like [Xlint:invalidAbsoluteTypeName](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23780951/xlintinvalidabsolutetypename) ***BUT*** I don't want to add Spring dependencies which I'm not using. I just want this AOP pointcut ignored. Other workarounds like splitting up the pointcuts to different jars imho give too much overhead. Is there any way to have Spring AOP just ignore this pointcut, or e.g. set the pointcut to st like if-exists(class)?

To show why I think separating is causing way too much overhead have a look at my aspect structure:

```
@Aspect
public class PerformanceLoggingAspect {
    private LogWriter logWriter;

    @Inject
    public PerformanceLoggingAspect(LogWriter logWriter) {
        this.logWriter = logWriter;
    }

    @Around("within(@org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController *)")
    public Object withinARestController(ProceedingJoinPoint pjp) throws Throwable {
        return proceedWithLogging(pjp, MetingType.REST);
    }

    @Around("within(@org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.annotation.Endpoint *)")
    public Object withinAnEndpoint(ProceedingJoinPoint pjp) throws Throwable {
        return proceedWithLogging(pjp, MetingType.BERICHT);
    }

    @Around("within(@javax.inject.Named *)")
    public Object withinAService(ProceedingJoinPoint pjp) throws Throwable {
        return proceedWithLogging(pjp, MetingType.SERVICE);
    }

    private Object proceedWithLogging(ProceedingJoinPoint pjp, String metingType) throws Throwable {
        (... Working code (performance logging) if the annotation is on the classpath...)
    }
}
```

***Update:*** I tried creating a `@NeedsClass("any.package.Class")` which is a `@Conditional` annotation from spring-context. The condition class is a  `ClasspathCondition` which checked if the classloader could load that given class. But the error occurs before the condition gets evaluated so I'm afraid this is a dead end. But if you're curious:

The `@NeedsClass` annotation I tried

```
    @Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
    @Target({ElementType.TYPE, ElementType.METHOD})
    @Documented
    @Conditional(ClasspathCondition.class)
    public @interface NeedsClass {
        String[] value();
    }
```

The `Condition` implementation. I had logging here, which never got written

```
    public class ClasspathCondition implements Condition {
        @Override
        public boolean matches(ConditionContext context, AnnotatedTypeMetadata metadata) {
            try {
                String[] classes = (String[]) metadata.getAnnotationAttributes(NeedsClass.class.getName()).get("classes");
                for (String clazz : classes) {
                    ClassUtils.resolveClassName(clazz, context.getClassLoader());
                }
                return true;
            } catch (Throwable t) { /* noOp() */}
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Try for injecting beans: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22872161/1888799

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For now I have a **workaround**:

- I created a superclass with the method:

  ```
  protected Object proceedWithLogging(ProceedingJoinPoint pjp, String metingType) throws Throwable {
      (... code which adds performance logging ...)
  }
  ```
- I created 4 subclasses with each the `@Aspect` annotation, and 1 method calling the super. For example this one targets JMS:

  ```
  @Aspect
  public class JmsPerformanceLogger extends PerformanceLoggingAspect {
      @Inject
      private LogWriter logWriter;

      @Around("within(@org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.annotation.Endpoint *)")
      public Object withinAnEndpoint(ProceedingJoinPoint pjp) throws Throwable {
          return proceedWithLogging(pjp, MetingType.BERICHT);
      }
  }
  ```
- As a downside I have to configure all different beans which I need within my app, and I **cannot** add one simple configuration file as shown below, with all beans preconfigured:

  ```
  @Configuration
  public class PerformanceloggingConfig {

      @Bean
      public LogWriter performanceLogWriter(){
          return new DefaultLogWriter();
      }

      @Bean
      public JmsPerformanceLogger jmsPerformanceLogger(){
          return new JmsPerformanceLogger();
      }
      @Bean
      public RestPerformanceLogger restPerformanceLogger(){
          return new RestPerformanceLogger();
      }
      @Bean
      public ServicesPerformanceLogger servicesPerformanceLogger(){
          return new ServicesPerformanceLogger();
      }
      @Bean
      public DaoPerformanceLogger daoPerformanceLogger(){
          return new DaoPerformanceLogger();
      }
  }
  ```

  And therefore also not the handy annotation to autoconfig the class:

  ```
  @Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
  @Target(ElementType.TYPE)
  @Import(PerformanceloggingConfig.class)
  public @interface EnablePerformanceLogging {

  }
  ```

  But for now adding these 4 beans when I need them, makes it possible to differentiate per app. But of course this is still a workaround, as I want to use `@EnablePerformanceLogging` and be done with it. If anyone has a better answer, pls tell me